# How to force http or https with Url.Action<tController>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, https, mvccontrib

I'm using the strongly typed Url.Action method from MvcContrib to do all of my url generation on my site.

For example:

```
Url.Action<CategoriesController>(c => c.List())
```

Is there a way to force the urls generated by this method to use http or https?  Right now it seems to just be creating urls relative to the current page.  So, for example, if I'm on an https page it makes all my header and footer links use https even though I don't want those pages to be secure.

Something like:

```
Url.Action<CategoriesController>(c => c.List(), protocol: "https")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MvcContrib's Action<T> extension doesn't support generating https URLs.

Internally, this method calls into Microsoft's LinkBuilder.BuildUrlFromExpression method from the MvcFutures library which is very simplistic. It only supports generating simple relative links and doesn't support many of the features build into the normal Url.Action method including https and areas. As long as  the MvcContrib extensions rely on this method internally, it won't support these additional features.

You'd be better off sticking with Mvc's normal Url.Action if you want to take advantage of these features.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this totally answers your question, but you can add the `[RequireHttps]` attribute to any action (or controller) you want to force under SSL.  Since Url.Action will create the fully-qualified URL based on the current scheme/authority, it will initially show links to http://site/controller/action.  But the RequireHttps attribute will switch the scheme over to HTTPS for you, and once within that scheme, Url.Action will appropriately return the https://site/controller/action URLs.

Comment: That's not what I want.  I want to be able to tell Url.Action<T> which protocol to use, so that it doesn't generate an incorrect url and then rely on something like [RequireHttps] to do a redirect and fix it later.  I want it to generate the correct url the first time.

Comment: I found this version of Url.Action(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232.aspx - looks like that should do exactly what you're asking

Comment: But like I said i'm not using Url.Action().  I'm using Url.Action<T>() from MvcContrib.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with that component, but I would be surprised if their extension methods didn't cover all the same bases as the UrlHelper methods that come boxed with MVC.

Comment: You''re wrong about Url.Action automatically generating a full https://xyz link based on the presence of [RequireHttps] on the action or controller.  Down voted.  That would be darned nice, but it just generates the usual relative url.