# ASP .NET MVC - forcing not to use SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can force a controller / action in ASP .NET MVC to use HTTPS.

How can I do other way around? i.e., I do not want my public web-pages to be accessible via HTTPS. Reason being: they are use external scripts and images, it gives not-so-good cross across https signs.

Do I need to use custom attrib?

F1 F1 ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do the OPPOSITE of \[RequireHttps(Redirect=true)\] in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158214/how-do-i-do-the-opposite-of-requirehttpsredirect-true-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206019/how-to-force-http-or-https-with-url-actiontcontroller) maybe of your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **[UrlRouting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)** module in IIS7 to force SSL / no SSL traffic.
I prefer IIS configuration as any changes do not impact the application source code.